# Google OAuth seems broken for Imgur API

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, imgur

### Overview

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth2 for Imgur API in Android, but the Google OAuth redirection URL is broken:

```
https://imgur.com/signin/google
```

#### Details

I followed the documentation and use the `oauth2/authorize`endpoint. I registered an Imgur Application, and filled up the `client id` and `client secret`. Then I managed to build a request like this:

```
GET https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={{client_id}}
&client_secret={{client_secret}}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&response_type=token
```

The Login Page showed up successfully.

Clicking on **Facebook**, **Twitter**, **Yahoo** work fine.

[image]

But only **Google** OAuth page is not working :

[image]

So I did some checking on the redirect URL, here are how they look like:

1. Facebook

```
https://imgur.com/signin/facebook?
redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={{client_id}}
&client_secret={{client_secret}}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&response_type=token
```

2. Twitter

```
https://imgur.com/signin/twitter?
redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={{client_id}}
&client_secret={{client_secret}}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&response_type=token
```

3. Google

```
https://imgur.com/signin/google?
redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={{client_id}}
&client_secret={{client_secret}}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&response_type=token
```

4. Yahoo

```
https://imgur.com/signin/yahoo?
redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={{client_id}}
&client_secret={{client_secret}}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&response_type=token
```

I noticed that all of the redirection URL looks the same. And all of them work fine asides from Google's redirect, so I think Google's OAuth redirect URL is broken.

Here's a clickable version of those urls (this will simulate clicking those buttons in the login page of Imgur), you can click on each of them, only Google's is not working.

1. Facebook

   - https://imgur.com/signin/facebook?redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&response_type=token
2. Twitter

   - https://imgur.com/signin/twitter?redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&response_type=token
3. Google

   - https://imgur.com/signin/google?redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&response_type=token
4. Yahoo

   - https://imgur.com/signin/yahoo?redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&response_type=token

I'm not sure where to file bugs for Imgur API, from the documentation it says that I should post to StackOverflow. Hopefully Imgur team or someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the response code / content returned by google?

Comment: The response I got when I clicked on Google is just a HTTP 404, you can simulate the call by visiting: https://imgur.com/signin/google?redirect=https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&response_type=token

Comment: Of course it is 404, because client ID `cliend_id` doesn't exist. You need to create client/secret first.

Comment: I've registered and setup the client/secret, I just didn't show that in the writing of this question. In fact you don't need to fill in the client/secret and those URL should still work, try clicking on Facebook/Twitter/Yahoo links, they all work well. Without the client id/secret, it will only affect the redirection after that. That's why i think Google links are broken, since the other 3 are working fine for me.

Comment: I have the same issue